# Google OR Tools: Employee Scheduling with availability constraint

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

Following the nurse scheduling example from [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling), I'm trying to add more constraints to the problem. For instance: nurse A cannot work shifts 2 and 3 on Monday, nurse B can only work shifts 1 and 3 across all days.

How would one go about implementing a constraint like this?

If it's not possible in OR-tools, please give suggestions on how I can implement something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your examples, all you need to do is add a constraint that prevents the shift from being assigned to that specific nurse:

```
   solver.Add(shifts[(2, 1)] != 3)  # Nurse 2 cannot be assigned shift 3 on day 1
```

More generally:

```
   solver.Add(shifts[(j, i)] != n)  # Nurse j cannot be assigned shift n on day i
```

Obviously you will want to do this in a loop to simplify it if possible.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, didn't know it was so straightforward. And here I was digging through their C++ documentation for things like `MakeLessThanOrEqualTo`